# What is the correct format of Json string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, string

I'am trying to display a Json string and I have some douts if my string is correct...

This is what i've done so far:

```js
//defining tehe string
var test = "{\"data\":[[100.50, 170.00, \"13/04/2022\", \"Vigente\", 14, 15]]}";

//return my string
return Json(test);

//NOTE -- I'am using C# controler to make this work
```

and this is what I have to follow ---
[Image that i trying to display like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTZRV.png)

**I'am doing this right**, if not whats is the right sintaxe to display that?

Comment: Why do you have a double [[ character? What error or behavior are you experiencing (you posted the question for a reason, what caused it)?

Comment: Have you tried using an online validator? If not, there are more than a few that you can just paste your string and determine if it's valid json. [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com/) | [JsonFormatter](https://jsonformatter.org/)

Comment: I want display the json like the image does, they are datas from a table, and if is not the same as the image, they are not going to work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DO NOT ATTEMPT TO MANUALLY CREATE JSON**

You should never attempt to generate JSON yourself like this as it is prone to errors. Anyway, `Json()` takes an object to serialize and will do it for you.

What you should do is:

```
var test = new {
    data = new List<List<object>>{
        new List<object>{ 100.50, 170.00, "13/04/2022", "Vigente", 14, 15 }
    }
};

return Json(test);
```

Even better would be to create a ViewModel object that you can populate  instead of using an anonymous type.

Comment: It is that what i've been looking for @phuzi, super worked for me!! Thanks a lot dude 